# When should "Don't ask next time" check box take effect?

Tags: checkboxes, popup, modal-windows

for example, suppose I have a popup like that:

[image]

I know the popup would not appear next time when the user clicks 'Yes' with the box checked.

but how about the following situations:

1. the user clicks 'No' but 'Don't ask next time' checked
2. 'Don't ask next time' checked but the application/windows closed

My question is: When should 'Don't ask next time' check box take effect?

1. Take effect immediately (popup wouldn't show next time if box checked but the application/window closed)
2. Take effect after 'Yes' or 'No' is selected
3. Take effect only after 'Yes' is selected

which one should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is highly depends of the kind of an action you're going to apply, perhaps, other options should be considered for a yes / no dialog.

A general recommendation would be to take into account a status of the checkbox for both available options. Otherwise it doesn't make any sense in case a user always picks the one that *implicitly* not affected by the selected checkbox.

Let's have a look how similar task solved at IntelliJ IDEA (an IDE software) when a user opens a project while working at another one:

[image]

The checkbox affects two actionable options (<kbd>This Window</kbd> and <kbd>New Window</kbd>), and takes no effect in case the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button is pushed. In the latter case, the user will be asked again next time.

Since the user workflow can change over time it is nice to provide an option that rollbacks the effect of a checkbox and allows a user to decide each time when an action is about to be performed.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: When should 'Don't ask next time' check box take effect?

If you're offering the user an option 'Don't ask next time', and the user checked that checkbox, that means they do not want to see that dialog again. You should not show it again regardless how the dialog was closed.

If the user found that dialog useful, they would not have checked 'Don't ask me next time'.

Having said that, they are still allowed to change their mind in the future, and it's good practice to have the option to reset the saved setting. One way to do that is to have a button under Settings that does that, see this example from a game application:

[image: Reset setting example]